# Is it a good idea to have an identical topic (plant identification) on both GL and Biology?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am an active participant on [Gardening and landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), which allows plant/fungus identification under the tag [identification], and there are currently 455 [questions with this tag](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification).

I've also been on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), where the tags [botany] and [species identification] are used for the exact same purpose. On Biology, there are currently 23 [questions on this topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/botany+species-identification).

I know it isn't too big a deal, but wouldn't it be better to have only one site cover that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the times you are right. Cross-posting is not desired, since that brings separate answers to the same question, where the goal of SE is to have a single question/answer set.

But cross-posting isn't the case here. In the case of the same, or related question, usually from different users, there isn't always a problem as long as it is on-topic for the site being asked. Think of cases where answers between sites can have a different point of view. Questions might fit well on multiple sites.

If you intend to ask a question yourself, pick the site you think the question fits best. If it yields no result, you could delete and re-ask on the other site or if possible, flag the question and ask a mod to move your question.

Comment: This isn't cross posting though, it's simply that something is on topic on 2 sites.

Comment: Have a look at this: [What is this vigorous plant 'duplicate'](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/what-is-this-vigorous-plant) and [What is this fast growing plant with blue/black berries?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-with-blue-black-berries) On GL, and [What is the name of this plant?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/what-is-the-name-of-this-plant) on Bio. That's actually my reason for the question.

Answer (score 8):

Subject overlap isn't a problem.

But I'd see this as not even overlapping in all cases.  The experts on biology will be able to identify things that GL experts might have a harder time with, and vice versa.  They are two separate, though related, fields<sup>*</sup> and the reason for identification can be a very good reason to ask one group or the other.

<sup>*<sub>Pun intended</sub></sup>